# PhpSpreadsheet wont free used memory after loading a large file

Tags: php, excel, laravel, memory, phpspreadsheet

Im loading some huge Excel files with PhpSpreadsheet in a Laravel project running on a Linux Apache webserver. These worksheets are +50k rows long and take various GB of memory when read.

The issue I'm facing is that for some reason, even after unsetting the variables and closing the file as explained in the documentation: https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/creating-spreadsheet/#clearing-a-workbook-from-memory

```
$spreadsheet->disconnectWorksheets();
unset($spreadsheet);
```

The memory the process uses won't free up until I restart Apache, eventually crashing the server. Here´s my method for reading the files and returning the cell values in an array of rows.

```
public static function readFile($file, string $sheet = null): array
{
    $bookarray = array();
    $reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx();
    $reader->setReadDataOnly(true);
    $spreadsheet = $reader->load($file);

    if ($sheet != null) {
        $worksheet = $spreadsheet->getSheetByName($sheet);
        if ($worksheet == null) {
            $worksheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
        }
    } else {
        $worksheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
    }

    foreach ($worksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
        $rowarray = array();
        $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();

        foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
            array_push($rowarray, $cell->getValue());
        }

        array_push($bookarray, $rowarray);
        unset($rowarray);
        unset($cellIterator);
    }

    $bookarray = array_values($bookarray);
    $spreadsheet->disconnectWorksheets();
    unset($spreadsheet);
    unset($worksheet);
    unset($reader);

    return $bookarray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I looked more into it and found out that phpSpreadSheet has a memory leak when loading big .xlsx files, but not with .xls and .cvs files.

I migrated to another library.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).